# What would aliens use as raw materials?

Tags: aliens, engineering, architecture, materials, manufacturing

I just realized that on earth many natural resources used for building throughout history could be considered unique to earth, materials such as bone and wood are products of terrestrial evolution and are unlikely to be found in alien ecosystems, and while things like ore and stone would probably be present for humans it required the use of wood for us to be able to forge metals so even with metal ore an alien race might not be able to use it.
This problem gets even worse if the alien race doesn't live on the ground for example a race of creatures that live in the upper atmosphere of a gas giant, who would not have access to the ground and earthen materials.
So what materials might a primitive alien race use to make tools and buildings out of?

Comment: This is far too broad as written. You need to specify a. the living conditions of a specific alien species, b. the geological conditions of their planet and c. the biological resources available on that planet from other creatures. Consider it this way, if wood or bone were not available, then the life on that planet must provide some other structural materials, whether keratin, chitin, or calcium carbonate shells.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  Please note that this question isn't a good fit on our site.  The StackExchange model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  This question is very, very broad because you tell us nothing about the aliens, their world, their habitat and ecology, etc.  Basically, you're asking us to write your story for you, which is off-topic here.

Comment: Don't forget oil an coal. As far as we know, earth is the only place in the Universe that has oil an coal. Certainly it is not obtainable anywhere else in our solar system.

Comment: @JBH Basically this question isn't asking WB SE to write the story for the OP. For pity's sake re-read the criteria for Too Story-based. Time and time again Too Story-based is invoked promiscuously & incompetently.

Comment: @JustinThyme *"As far as we know, earth is the only place in the Universe that has oil an coal"* Only because we can't visit the planets and check.  The odds that in a universe of something like $10^{24}$ stars, likely all with many planets, there aren't rather a lot of planets with oil and coal just like Earth has is tiny.

Comment: @a4android, I did NOT vote to close as too-story-based.  In fact NONE of us that have voted cast that vote.  This question is asking us to start from nothing and figure out everything.  Based on the premise that most people are here for the sake of a story, that's writing their story for them, making the question too broad (You can look that up on your own time).

Comment: I haven't decided what the aliens look like or their physiology or history yet since those details will come about later What I am asking is what sort of basic natural resources that are suitable for building might exist on other worlds specifically ones that are not biological in origin and could be used by a primitive civilization. If that question is not specific enough I'm not sure how to specify it better.

Comment: @TurkeyCannon, Please understand that your question is unanswerable.  The one and only resource we know will be on other planets is rocks.  Even water is simply a guess.

Comment: Why is it unanswerable? Isn't there ways of predicting how common certain elements would be in the universe? (I always hear that hydrogen is the most abundant element in the universe), All I want to know is what common elements are suitable for building with and potentially workable by primitive societies

Comment: "*Isn't there ways of predicting how common certain elements would be in the universe?*"  Sure. 
 Physicists did that ages ago. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements  What this really needs is "-1 does not show sufficient research".

Comment: @TurkeyCannon Its going to be whatever they can get their hands on that is stable. If there is a planet made of coal, then they will build out of coal. Likewise, if there is a planet made out of only gas, they probably won't build anything because they would of evolved to live in the gas and not require shelter. Its broad because it depends not only on the planet, but how the creature evolved. Humans are smart and built shelter, but other apex predators don't always need to. You make do with what is around you, there is no proper answer to cover it all.

Comment: @TurkeyCannon The general availability of elements doesn't help much.  It's how they are put together on your particular planet that matters.  Consider that the difference between a human body and a pile of wet dirt is merely organization of the atoms.  Clearly we care more about one than the other.

Comment: @JBH Asking a question about a premise for a world doesn't constitute asking about how to write the actual story. To make any claim that the OP was getting WB to write their story for them is hot air. It's not about whether the question was closed as Too Story-based. It's a matter to querying what is a spurious claim that isn't at all helpful for the OP. I had already noted the likelihood of its being Too Broad. It's easy for any of us to go down paths to nowhere unless we consider carefully what we comment. We all make mistakes there.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what was wrong with my question, from what I can tell it seems to be no more vague or specific than any other question I've seen on the site and I don't see how it  could be interpreted as me having other users "write my story for me" since this question is only a fact check regarding a single aspect of a story and is not the general premise or focus of the story at all. Would rephrasing the question as "What naturally occurring inorganic elements or materials can be easily used to make tools or structures without requiring the use of advanced technology?" work?

Answer (score 2):

This is awfully hypothetical, but the short answer is "Whatever is left over when life forms on that planet die".

If you think about it, MOST of the primitive raw materials humans (and other terrestrial tool-using species) have ever used are bits left over from other living things after they've died. Vines, fronds, bones, sinew, hide, wood, it's all parts of other living things.

So, whatever the living things on that world leave behind when they die that's solid, that's your raw materials.

Add to that "any naturally occuring objects that your species can pick up", and that covers rocks, and that's pretty much it in terms of raw materials for primitive life.

Comment: Please, please, PLEASE don't take this the wrong way.... but yours is the best non-answer answer I've ever seen.  (A non-answer because it doesn't actually help the OP other than to point out he hasn't written his backstory.)  I'm giving you +1 just for the chutzpah.

Comment: Well, I mean, I'm flattered, I guess? I was really attempting to help the OP though, not so much by pointing out he hadn't written his backstory, but by helping him see how he can figure out the answer to his own question once he does? If that makes sense?

Comment: Oh, yeah.  I understand what you were doing.  He asked an unanswerable question and you took a level shot at answering it.  Hence the +1.  "Officially" you should avoid answering unanswerable questions.  It's better to teach the OP to ask better questions than to provide unavoidably weak answers to weak questions.

Comment: @JBH  You mean the answer out-chutzpahs the worst/best of my non-answers?

Comment: That's solid? What about oil and coal? Methane?

Comment: @JustinThyme, I was well impressed and feel no shame lobbing some rep.

Comment: @JustinThyme I would love to see us building houses with oil and coal. It was already a disaster with wood https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Fire_of_London . The question does refer to tools and buildings and this answer reverse to primitive materials/life.

Comment: @Shadowzee My answer refers to the .'solid' aart of 'world leave behind when they die that's solid'. The fact that oil is used in the machines that build our houses, I feel satisfies the criteria 'used for building'.

Comment: And, of course, there are plastics. From oil. you know.